# Losing the value of a FileUpload textbox when a dropdown list selection changes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having an dropdownlistbox and fileupload control.After selecting a file from upload control,if i change the dropdownlist value(postback occurs) then the file path i chosen earlier is shown empty.
here is my code:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblupload" runat="server" Text="Upload a file: "></asp:Label>                
   <asp:FileUpload ID="upload" runat="server" Width="320" Height="18" BorderColor="Gray" BorderWidth="1" />
   <asp:Label ID="Perimission" runat="server" Text="Perimission"></asp:Label>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" >
        <asp:ListItem Text="Everybody"  Value="Everybody"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Students"  Value="Students"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Selected Users"  Value="Selected Users"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: This is a security thingie. Textboxes maintain their state by adding the value="..." attribute, but a file upload should not allow this since it would be possible to specify files on the user's computer. You would then be able to add a thousand fileuploads, randomly guess paths to common cookie containers, and do a autopostback to grab them. Not really something you would want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if you really need that autopostback on the dropdownlist. But clear it and you're ok. FileUpload values won't be saved during postback..

Comment: if the value of the dropdownlistbox is selected users,then i am showing 2 button controls and 2 listbox controls which are not shown at the pageload time

Comment: Might want to do that client-side; already build the buttons and listbox controls (with runat="server") and display them using javascript

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick workaround you can use:

Add a ScriptManager to your page.

Put the dropdownlists in an AJAX [UpdatePanel](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/) and also display the buttons and listboxes in the UpdatePanel.

This will make the dropdownlists cause a partial, asynchronous postback rather than a full page post-back, thus the FileUpload control will be able to retain it's value.

I know that it's not the most efficient way to do it, but it's an easy way out, and also would be aesthetically better for the user as the page does not appear to reload just because of selecting a value in a dropdownlist.

But, remember to keep your FileUpload control outside the UpdatePanel, otherwise the FileUpload will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The FileUpload control posts the selected file on the next postback. Because changing the dropdown initiates a postback, the file is uploaded when changing another item in the DropDownList.

You can test this by putting this code in your page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (upload.PostedFile != null)
    {
        Response.Write("<p>" + upload.PostedFile.FileName + "</p>");
    }
}
```